# Can I restart a docker container from within the container terminal?

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I am making a Sinatra App inside a container, But whenever I want to see the changes I have to detach and run:

`docker restart <container_ID>`

to see the changes.

Is there any way that I could restart the docker from within to see the changes?

I cloned https://github.com/tcnksm-sample/docker-sinatra.git

Build `sudo docker build -t sinatra .`

Run container `sudo docker run -d -p 4567:4567 sinatra`

Enter the container terminal `sudo docker exec -it <container_ID> bash`

Changed the app.rb file but nothing changed on http://localhost:4567,
So I detach from the container and ran `docker restart <container_ID>` to see the changes. Since I am going to change the app.rb alot It is so inconvenient for every time I change something I have to detach and run `docker restart <container_ID>`

Comment: What container are you using? How does the Dockerfile look like? how do you run sinatra? You have to give us _something_ to work with ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to restart the all docker engine itself.

If your Dockerfile pull the changes from a repo, and redo a `bundle install`, as in [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/luisbebop/docker-sinatra-hello-world/blob/f6415ad6ae01d71deb05a60fa097a6bb67b605a9/Dockerfile#L6), all you need to do would be, as [in this example](https://github.com/luisbebop/docker-sinatra-hello-world#upgrade-the-container):

```
# on docker server or the same machine
$ sudo docker stop container-id
$ sudo docker pull luisbebop/docker-sinatra-hello-world
$ sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 luisbebop/docker-sinatra-hello-world
```

Comment: what should I do if I want to change the ruby file to make my own application? Shouldn't I attach the container terminal then change the server.rb file and see the changes?  all within the container terminal

Comment: @abdelrahmankhaled it is best to stop, rebuild and restart the container, to ensure reproducibility. If you modify directly from within a docker exec bash session, those changes will be lost once the container stops and is removed.

Comment: @abdelrahmankhaled my answer stands, in regard of your Dockerfile: https://github.com/tcnksm-sample/docker-sinatra/blob/9afef691a93593db30960a4c49958396fce7701b/Dockerfile#L18-L19

Comment: Can't I run sudo docker commit after the changes to save it ?

Comment: @abdelrahmankhaled yes, before docker rm, you can commit and create a new image. Another approach would be to mount the sources through a volume (https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/), but that is not how your Dockerfile was done.